# Root FS Read only: Remounting gives "cannot change data mode on remount" when not changing data mode

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, ext4

After messing with the settings in fstab, my root filesystem is being mounted read-only.

I was able to solve this error in the past by running

```
# remount -o remount,rw /
```

However, I am getting the error "cannot change data mode on remount".  I understand that this means that the "data=" option does not match between the mounting and remounting.  The problem is, no matter what option I give for the data mode, it gives this same error.

According to `mount`, `/` is mounted as `ro,relatime,data=ordered`. However `-o remount,rw,data=ordered` gives the same error.

According to `/etc/fstab`, `/` is supposed to be mounted as `discard,errors=remount-ro,noatime,data=writeback`.  However `-o rmount,rw,data=writeback` gives the same error.

even `data=journal` has the same error.

I have also tried to enable and disable other options listed in `mount` and `/etc/fstab`, but nothing will cause mount to do anything other than output this error.

How to I remount this drive as read-write?  What is causing this nonsensical error?

Comment: What is your boot loader?  (to provide more specific instructions)

Comment: grub2 with debian gnu/linux 4.3.3

Answer (score 3):

It's reading the data option from fstab and for some silly reason the command line parameters are not overriding...
Mount does not read fstab if device and mountpoint are
fully specified, e.g.:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

so

```
remount -o remount,rw,data=ordered /dev/sda1 /
```

or whatever your disk is named should work!

Answer (score 1):

After starting your computer, in the GRUB menu, choose the regular configuration and press <kbd>e</kbd>.  It will then prompt you for extra parameters and you put `rw` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

This will override the problem you created and you will then be able to go fix it.

If you don't get the GRUB menu when you boot, hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> when the system is about to start.

Comment: Some Linux distributions have started booting with `rw` by default, and no longer put `/` in fstab at all.

Comment: This is obviously not his case!

Comment: The thing is this does not precisely answer/explain the OP, since the question is why that error on a remount that "should" work, but not how to avoid the ro mount (which can be necessary in some case/distro for fsck)

Comment: I reread the question and actually think that OP knows exactly why this happened and simply doesn't know how to solve it.